# Dynamically insert data into javascript chart using Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using Google Charts in my webapp. Inside of my controller I pass a object holding data that later I access using method formatData() which returns data formatted to String. That's how output from this method looks like:

```
"[ [new Date(2017,4,27), 116.42], [new Date(2017,4,26), 116.26], [new Date(2017,4,25), 116.05] ]"
```

How I insert data inside of my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
      /*<![CDATA[*/
      data.addRows( [[${reco.formatData()}]] );
      /*]]>*/
</script>
```

But Thymeleaf doesn't interpret output as 2d array instead reads it as ordinary string. In HTMLS's source code looks like that:

```
data.addRows( '[ [new Date(2017,4,27), 116.42], [new Date(2017,4,26), 116.26], [new Date(2017,4,25), 116.05] ]');
```

Beacuse of quotation marks code is not working, what should I do to get rid of them? Let me know if there is better approach to insert data into chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In thymeleaf 3:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
      /*<![CDATA[*/
      data.addRows( /*[(@{${reco.formatData()}})]*/ );
      /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working, source code looks the same as the code above.

Comment: Thank you for a tip, it was not working because I had old Thymeleaf 2 version. After update your code is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Question already has an (accepted) answer, but here a different viewpoint:

I think there is a misconception of what `th:inline="javascript"` does. It takes the result of the expression and formats *a JavaScript object of it* (JSON to be specific I think). If your method returns a String, it will also be a String in the JavaScript code. This is a feature and not a bug.

Alternative solutions:

- Return the "correct" type from the Java code, not a String. If you want an array in JavaScript, return an array (or List) from Java code.
- To insert string as is without interception, replace `th:inline="javascript"` with `th:inline="text"`.