# Writing a String with thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I am trying to create dynamic graphs with thymeleaf and Google Charts. I want to create something like:

> var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Var 1', 'Var2'],[a,0.20],[b,0.20],[c,0.06]]);

The code I saw in the tutorials to do this is this one:

> var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ [[${data}]] ]);

Where data is a String I added as an attribute to the model and which contains all the data in the format I need it. But when it is executed, this is the script created.

> var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(["['Var 1', 'Var2'],[a,0.20],[b,0.20],[c,0.06]"]);

It has " in the beggining and in the end, which makes the function to fail since the data is considered a string. How can I print the string without the "?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you use `th:inline`?

Comment: Yes! I am using <script type="text/javascript" src="js/grafica.js" th:inline="javascript"></script>.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44168204/1463522) helps you.